# Unable to run C++ code (mainly include files (.h) missing)

Tags: c++, r

I have tried the following in R 3.6.3 and more recently in R 4.0.
Running Mac OSX Catalina. I have version Xcode 11.4.1 and did
`xcode-select --install` to ensure I have the command line tools.

When an R package has to be compiled from source in Rstudio, I get the error that config.h
is not found. I get similar errors when trying Rcpp (some .h is not found.for example math.h).

If anyone has a work-around, let me know. and thanks. I searched quite a bit on this issue
but have been unable to resolve it.

```
* installing *source* package ‘pkgbuild’ ...
** package ‘pkgbuild’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (pkgbuild)
* installing *source* package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I./lib/  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c capture.c -o capture.o
In file included from capture.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/Rinternals.h:44:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R_ext/Arith.h:41:
In file included from /usr/local/include/math.h:8:
In file included from /usr/local/include/features.h:10:
/usr/local/include/forwards.h:10:10: fatal error: 'config.h' file not found
#include "config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [capture.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted something similar on a mailing list devoted to R Developers. After some discussion, it became apparent there there were conflicting header files located in /usr/local/include and /usr/local/library. These *.h files were being chosen rather than the ones associated with R.

One solution (which worked) was to create a directory called ~/.R and then inside this directory, have a Makevars file with the following one line:

CPPFLAGS = -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk

A second solution was to rename /usr/local/library and /usr/local/include to make it so that these files were unavailable to R when trying to compile from C++ source or using the package Rcpp.

Hopefully, these solutions will assist others if they have a similar problem.